# How to use addition within ifelse in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a `df data.frame` that consists of 4 variables `a, b, c and d` and 100 observations. There are missing values in variables `b and c`

```
set.seed(123)
a <- runif(100, 0.005, 2.3)
b <- runif(100, 0.2, 4.3)
c <- runif(100, 0.03, 1.6) 
d <- runif(100, 0.05, 2.4)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d) 
df[c(1:4,8:10, 30:35, 60:65,90:97), c(2,3)]<-NA

head(df)
#          a        b         c          d
#1  0.6649904       NA        NA 1.89375188
#2  1.8141603       NA        NA 0.07216028
#3  0.9436020       NA        NA 1.88080482
#4  2.0315249       NA        NA 1.76406803
#5  2.1633724 2.179900 0.6620401 1.53080985
#6  0.1095522 3.850436 1.4119871 1.18014045
```

I want to create column `E` in which

if  `c` = `NA` ==> `E` = `a+d` else `E`= `a + b + c`

I tried doing it using `ifelse` as below

```
df$E <- 0
df$E <- ifelse(df$c == NA, 
               df$a + df$d, 
               df$a+df$b+df$c)
```

The code runs but the `E` column was filled by `NA`. Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply :

```
df$E <- ifelse(is.na(df$c), 
           df$a + df$d, 
           df$a+df$b+df$c)
```